# Функция suspend не выполняется

Tags: kotlin

При прописывании в коде функции suspend программа вылетает. Даже если функция пустая.

```
package com.example.test

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        }
suspend fun counter(view: View) {
        }
    }

}
```

Функция вызывается нажатием кнопки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Эх, чувак, используй delay(1000) для задержки. А вызывать suspend ты должен из другого потока. 
Разберись как положить вызов в lifecycleScope.launch {...}.
И да, не надо передавать вьюху в функцию, это ошибка.